# Is there a way to use Linq in the case and avoid the for cycle in the example?

Tags: c#

I've got this sample code(using and class deleted due to restrictions):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            var storedElements = new SortedSet<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                var command = Console.ReadLine().Split().ToList();
                //Maybe Linq above to avoid the for cycle?

                for (int k = 0; k < command.Count; k++)
                {
                    storedElements.Add(command[k]);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", storedElements));
        }
    }
}
```

The whole idea is to have this:

```
var command = Console.ReadLine().Split().ToList();

    for (int k = 0; k < command.Count; k++)
    {
                storedElements.Add(command[k]);
    }
```

avoided. In this sense, if possible, what should I add to make this work with Linq:

storedElements.Add(Console.ReadLine().Split()//WhatToAdd;

Comment: AddRange is not available on SortedSet, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SortedSet has a method called [UnionWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.unionwith?view=netframework-4.7.2). 
So you can use it in place of the current loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var command = Console.ReadLine().Split().ToList();
    storedElements.UnionWith(command);
}
```

This seems convenient at first, but looking at the source code I am not sure if it is better in performance than your original loop. Better test it if this is in critical code.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

storedElements.UnionWith(Console.ReadLine().Split());

Hashsets do not have AddRange()

Thank you!